# CSV on mac doesn't recognize numbers

Tags: r, macos, csv, numeric

I am trying to do some analyses with R and experienced some problems when doing it with my Macbook. When reading the csv file in R it tells me that the numeric values are empty.

That's how it looks like when I try to run an analysis:

```
pall.values = numeric()
 df <- data.frame(Estimate=numeric(50), P.value=numeric(50))
 for (i in 2:51){  #change the column range based on your data sheet
     x <- cor.test(fdata[,c(i)],fdata$ARHQ_dad)
     df$Estimate[i-3]=x$estimate
     df$P.value[i-3]=x$p.value
 }
```

Then this error occurs:

> Error in cor.test.default(fdata[, c(i)], fdata$ARHQ_dad) : 'x' must be
>   a numeric vector

The csv itself recognizes the values as numbers since I used the Data to Column function and divided the columns by spaces and commas. However, in R it doesn't seem to work...

I hope somebody knows the answer to this (simple) problem.

Comment: What's in `fdata`? We have no idea what your data looks like so it's not easy to help. When asking for help, you should include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data that we can use to run and test your code.

Comment: Fdata describes the dataset I am using which contains a matrix of 83 rows (subjects of a study) and 50 columns (brain data) that looks something like this:   node_13  node_14  node_15  node_16  node_17  node_18  node_19  node_20  node_21  node_22  node_23  node_24  node_25  node_26
1 0.188296 0.195567 0.203880 0.212286 0.220239 0.227744 0.233379 0.237880 0.242103 0.244735 0.246257 0.246948 0.247150 0.247076